# Is there a way to specify the argument positions in the format string for `string.format`?

Tags: lua, printf

In C, I can tell `printf` to print the arguments in an order different than the order they are passed in:

```c
printf("%2$d %1$d\n", 10, 20);
//prints 20 10
```

However, if I try to do the same in Lua  I get an error:

```lua
print(string.format("%2$d %1$d\n", 10, 20))
```

```
invalid option '%$' to 'format'
```

Is there a way to create a Lua format string that causes string.format to write the second argument before the first? I am working with an internationalization and changing the format string is easy but changing the argument order is much more tricky.

I would have expected the technique that I used in C to work with Lua because, [according to the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.format), `string.format` should receive the same parameters as `sprintf`. Are `%2$` directives not part of ANSI C or is the Lua manual just forgetting to mention that they are not supported?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, no. [`%2$` directives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Format_placeholders) are a POSIX extension, thus not part of ANSI C or Lua. This has been brought up on the [Lua mailing list](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2009-03/msg00450.html) before, and [according to lhf](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2009-03/msg00453.html), the feature was around in versions prior to Lua 5 but was removed with that version's release. In the same thread, [a wiki page of alternatives](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringInterpolation) was suggested.

If you really want the `%2$` style, then it's not too difficult to cook up your own fix either.

---

```
local function reorder(fmt, ...)
    local args, order = {...}, {}

    fmt = fmt:gsub('%%(%d+)%$', function(i)
        table.insert(order, args[tonumber(i)])
        return '%'
    end)

    return string.format(fmt, table.unpack(order))
end

print(reorder('%2$d %1$d\n', 10, 20))
```

Comment: POSIX printf lets you print the same argument more than once (`%1$d  %1$d`) so your proposed solution doesn't do *exactly* the same thing. But thanks a lot anyway - I'd never find those threads without knowing the good search terms and now that I know that what I want can't be done I can start wondering what is the best workaround for my particular case.

Comment: @missingno Are you sure? I just tried `print(reorder('%2$d %2$d\n', 10, 50))`, and it returned `50 50` as expected.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was swapping the meanings of `args` and `order`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with `string.format`, but you can actually achieve almost the same result with `string.gsub`. The caveat here is that the last argument of string.gsub can be either string or table (with multiple values to replace)

So this code would do the trick:

```
local output = string.gsub("%2 %1 %2 %1\n", '%S+', {['%1'] = 10, ['%2'] = 20})
print(output)

> 20 10 20 10
```